# Using reflection to assign value to class fields

Tags: c#, reflection

I am calling multiple methods of a single web service. For every method, i need to create a unique request and have to pass site credentials and user credentials everytime which is a very repetitive task. Please find the code below.

```
ClientService.AddOrUpdateClientsRequest clientRequest = new ClientService.AddOrUpdateClientsRequest();
        // Create and fill credentials
        clientRequest.SourceCredentials = new ClientService.SourceCredentials();
        clientRequest.SourceCredentials.SourceName = sourcename;
        clientRequest.SourceCredentials.Password = password;
        clientRequest.SourceCredentials.SiteIDs = siteIDs;


        clientRequest.UserCredentials = new ClientService.UserCredentials();
        clientRequest.UserCredentials.Username = "Siteowner";
        clientRequest.UserCredentials.Password = "apitest1234";
        clientRequest.UserCredentials.SiteIDs = siteIDs;


 ClientService.AddOrUpdateClientsRequest updateClientRequest = new ClientService.AddOrUpdateClientsRequest();
            // Create and fill credentials
            updateClientRequest.SourceCredentials = new ClientService.SourceCredentials();
            updateClientRequest.SourceCredentials.SourceName = sourcename;
            updateClientRequest.SourceCredentials.Password = password;
            updateClientRequest.SourceCredentials.SiteIDs = siteIDs;


            updateClientRequest.UserCredentials = new ClientService.UserCredentials();
            updateClientRequest.UserCredentials.Username = "Siteowner";
            updateClientRequest.UserCredentials.Password = "apitest1234";
            updateClientRequest.UserCredentials.SiteIDs = siteIDs;

 ClientService.UploadClientDocumentRequest uploadRequest = new ClientService.UploadClientDocumentRequest();
```

// Assign credentials for UploadClientDocumentRequest object

How can i create a generic function to assign values to same credentials fields but different type of objects. I was looking at using reflection but didn't get anything online

Comment: You can simply write a method right.! to get a new clientrequest object with the default values put in.!

Comment: The type of client request objects are different. One is AddorUpdate object, another is UploadDocumentObject and there are more different objects but they all ask for the same credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use reflection. WCF proxy classes are generated as partials, so you can create a an interface to apply to all DTOs which contain these properties:

```
public interface IAuthorizedRequest
{
    SourceCredentials SourceCredentials { get; set; }
    UserCredentials UserCredentials { get; set; }
}
```

Then in a new or the same file, apply this interface to all those DTO classes:

```
// Merely apply the interface, the other partial contains the properties
public partial class AddOrUpdateClientsRequest : IAuthorizedRequest { }
public partial class SomeOtherRequest : IAuthorizedRequest { }
```

Then you can create a method which applies the credentials to any `IAuthorizedRequest`:

```
public void ApplyCredentials(IAuthorizedRequest request) 
{
    request.SourceCredentials = new ClientService.SourceCredentials();
    request.SourceCredentials.SourceName = sourcename;
    request.SourceCredentials.Password = password;
    request.SourceCredentials.SiteIDs = siteIDs;

    request.UserCredentials = new ClientService.UserCredentials();
    request.UserCredentials.Username = "Siteowner";
    request.UserCredentials.Password = "apitest1234";
    request.UserCredentials.SiteIDs = siteIDs;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var request = new AddOrUpdateClientsRequest();
ApplyCredentials(request);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful information on how shall i design my classes. I am still learning this art. Thanks again.